# strcmp results in false when strings are equal

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
        if(strcmp(pch,map[i].name)==0){
            printf("Equal\n");
            return 0;
        }
```

`pch` is read from a file, `map[i].name` has a known size of 64.
This works great for strings smaller than 64. when comparing these two strings below of size 63:

`file11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` and

```
file11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

everything is peachy and the result as expected is equal, but when these two (of size 64) are compared:

`file111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` and

```
file111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

the return is false.
I thought of doing:

```
        if(strncmp(pch,map[i].name,64)==0){
            printf("Equal\n");
            return 0;
        }
```

And it does work for strings of exact size of 64, but for strings that
are smaller the result is random.
What kind of quirkiness am i dealing with here?

EDIT: this is the full code:

```
    char * pch;
    char tempFilesNeeded[100*64+100];
    strcpy(tempFilesNeeded,map[i].filesNeeded);
    pch = strtok(tempFilesNeeded,",");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(pch,map[i].name)==0){
            printf("Equal\n");
            return 0;
        }

        pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if it's

```
char pch[64];
```

then you can't have 64 visible characters in there, since the last entry is needed for the termination. If you do have `"file111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"` in that array, it's not terminated and calling `strcmp()` on it invokes undefined behavior.

Also, as a minor point, saying that `strcmp()` returns "false" is wrong, since its return is *not* boolean. It returns the relation between the two first differing characters; if no characters differ the strings are equal, then it returns zero.

Comment: @Tom "map[i].name has a known size of 64" so he's point still holds.

Comment: @Tom You just can't put 64-char-length string in a 64-length char array.

Answer (score 5):

If one or both your arrays have an exact size of 64, you are missing the final '\0' ending the string.