# Pointers in C. Why the function isn´t working?

Tags: c, function, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does strcmp() return 0 when its inputs are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595450/why-does-strcmp-return-0-when-its-inputs-are-equal)
>   [strcmp results in false when strings are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380181/strcmp-results-in-false-when-strings-are-equal)

I really can´t get why the function check return true!!! I use strcmp to compare the char[] pointer (hello) and the array of chars "bar".

```
bool check(const char* word);
char pointer[] = "hello";  

int main (void)
{
    bool answer = check(pointer) ;

    if(answer == true)
        printf("true");
    else
        printf("false");

    return 0;
}

bool check(const char* word)
{
    printf(" word = %s ", word);

    if(strcmp( word , "bar"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` returns non-zero when strings are different.

Comment: Read The Fine Manual. Specifically, for [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Comment: is the other way around!!.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595450/why-does-strcmp-return-0-when-its-inputs-are-equal ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656475/strcmp-return-values-in-c

Answer (score 4):

`I really can´t get why the function check return true!!!`

Interestingly in raw basic C code there's no "true" or "false" (or "bool") with out including some extra header files (like stdbool.h)... but I digress..

It's not returning true. Read the manual on [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp). You can do this by `man 3 strcmp` on Linux or just google search "man strcmp".

The manual will tell you the return value of the function is:

> ... an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

Keep in mind that all integer values that are not 0 will be considered "true" for conditional checks. So that is to say in this code:

```
if(strcmp(word, "bar"))
```

Any word which is ***not*** "bar" will be "true". What you want for a match is if it is equal to zero:

```
if(strcmp(word, "bar") == 0)
```

---

side note, if you're going to declare something in the global scope like you do with

```
char pointer[] = "hello";
```

It's not needed to pass it to the function, you can access it globally, which is the point of a global. Globals are, however, generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

[strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) returns `0` if the strings are equal.

Your conditional should be negated:

```
if(!strcmp( word , "bar"))
    return true;
```

or compared to `0`:

```
if(strcmp( word , "bar") == 0)
    return true;
```